# Python Pandas read_csv float64 to string

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading below CSV file as *read_csv*

```
day,order,variant,variant_name
2020-05-04,OR_001,1000000548952,Product1
2020-05-04,OR_001,1000000056488,Product4
2020-05-04,OR_002,1000000528985,Product2
```

When I read this in a dataframe and then print the variant column

```
print(df_SalesOrders["variant"])
```

I get the below output.

```
0     1.000001e+12
1     1.000000e+12
2     1.000001e+12
```

Could someone please let me know how can I preserve the original number which I believe is treated as float64.

I tried the below code however that didn't help.

```
myarr = df_SalesOrders.variant.astype(str)
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: df_SalesOrders.variant = df_SalesOrders.variant.astype(str)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add you change to your dataframe

```
df_SalesOrders.variant = df_SalesOrders.variant.astype('int64')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. This has resolved the issue however only partially. The column is now displayed with 1 decimal place like below

1000000548952.0
1000000056488.0
1000000528985.0

How do I remove the decimal place? String formating?
Thanks again.

Comment: try `astype('int64') `

Answer (score 0):

Please call

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.4f}'.format 
df
```